# NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 File couldn’t be opened

Tags: swift4, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver

The file were created in old project in Objective-C.

```
NSKeyedArchiver* archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:dataForWrite];
[archiver encodeObject:dictVer forKey:@"cityVersionDict"];
[archiver finishEncoding];
BOOL flag = [dataForWrite writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

I want to read this file in new project in Swift4.0 by the code like this:

```
do {
    let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: path)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

then catch error:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “cityVersionDict.archiver” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=/Users/sam/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/51CD0088-EE62-4ED0-8660-4C6486BC7823/data/Containers/Data/Application/5740ADE1-4930-4968-B86F-7E2F5F99F5F8/Library/Caches/cityVersionDict.archiver}

In Objective-C ,this file can be read normally .I already double check the path is right. but still catch error. please help, thanks

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I find the problem is about the `URL`.

The `URL` must use `init(fileURLWithPath: String)` to created,

then `Data(contentsOf: URL)` can work fine.

Comment: LOL! Just spent an hour trying to change the permissions of my file. Thanks for this :D Filed under "Things I will never forget again." :D

Comment: But I am getting Media url as "assets-library://asset/asset.MP4?id=F65960BD-9AD8-4BBC-8C17-12345F10EB74E&ext=MP4". I think this is the problem and not able to figure out why? Any help??

Comment: @Mansuu.... Have u ever solved that issue :D ?